# How to reformat paragraph to have each sentence on a separate line?

Tags: text

Input:

```
Hi. I am John.
My name is John. Who are you ?
```

Output:

```
Hi
I am John
My name is John
Who are you
```

Comment: I was tempted to start a bounty for this one. It almost sounds impossible to do only with a text or a howto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    String line = "Hi. My name is John. Who are you ?";
    String[] sentences = line.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s+");
    for (String sentence : sentences) {
       System.out.println("[" + sentence + "]");
    }
```

This produces:

```
[Hi.]
[My name is John.]
[Who are you ?]
```

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info tutorials](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

  - [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
  - [Character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- [Java language guide: the for-each loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

---

If you're not comfortable using `split` (even though it's the recommended replacement for the "legacy" [`java.util.StringTokenizer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)), you can just use *only* [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) (which is more than adequate to do the job).

#### See also

- [Scanner vs. StringTokenizer vs. String.Split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691184/scanner-vs-stringtokenizer-vs-string-split)

Here's a solution that uses `Scanner`, which by the way `implements Iterator<String>`. For extra instructional value, I'm also showing an example of using [`java.lang.Iterable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) so that you can use the for-each construct.

```
    final String text =
        "Hi. I am John.\n" +
        "My name is John. Who are you ?";

    Iterable<String> sentences = new Iterable<String>() {
        @Override public Iterator<String> iterator() {
            return new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("\\s*[.!?]\\s*");
        }
    };

    for (String sentence : sentences) {
        System.out.println("[" + sentence + "]");
    }
```

This prints:

```
[Hi]
[I am John]
[My name is John]
[Who are you]
```

If this regex is still not what you want, then I recommend investing the time to educate yourself so you can take matters into your own hand.

#### See also

- [What is the Iterable interface used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059127/what-is-the-iterable-interface-used-for)
- [Why is Java’s Iterator not an Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839178/why-is-javas-iterator-not-an-iterable)

---

*Note*: the `final` modifier for the local variable `text` in the above snippet is a necessity. In an illustrative example, it makes for a concise code, but in your actual code you should refactor the anonymous class to its own named class and have it take `text` in the constructor.

#### See also

- [Anonymous vs named inner classes? - best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714602/anonymous-vs-named-inner-classes-best-practices)
- [Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-different)

Comment: @John: Then `split("[.!?]\\s+")`. Maybe even `split("\\s*[.!?]\\s+")`. Maybe even `split("\\s*[.!?]+\\s+")`. Feel free to clarify your unclear question to explain in more detail what is it that you want. More input, expected output, etc.

Comment: Hi... I am trying to take a file which contains a few lines of text.... and then split them up and store them in an array....

The problem that i am facing is that when i use a tokenizer it stops reading at each line.... and when i try to get in a while loop there.... it goes into an infinite loop.....

Comment: @John: I need to go to bed, but if you look up the API, it says that "`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead."

Comment: i've been reading bout split for the last couple of hours.... but all its done is confused me further

Comment: Thanks.... I'm still a bit confused on how line.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s+")

works.... as in how does (?<=[.!?])\\s+") work ??

Comment: It's a positive lookbehind (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `(?<=[.!?])` looks behind the current position, and see if there's a match for `[.!?]`. See for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559759/how-do-i-convert-camelcase-into-human-readable-names-in-java

Comment: thanks a ton.... the problem wasnt with the tokenizer but my loop that was reading from the file..... thanks for the java lesson on split though.... ended up using tht only... cheers !!!