# Stuck on Java 2D beginners tutorial

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, java-2d

I'm new to Java and I'm trying use Java 2D to try to get familiar with the language. I did the same thing with Python/Pygame to make simple games (snake, minesweeper etc) without too much struggle, but Java 2D seems a whole lot more complicated.

I'm following the tutorial on [this site](http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/introduction/), but in the SimpleEx.java code example I can't figure out what's going on:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            BasicEx ex = new BasicEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        }
});
```

It looks like a new method is being declared inside the .invokeLater() method call. Is this run() method a separate argument being passed into invokeLater()? Or is it adding this method to the new Runnable() object before the object is passed into the method?

Comment: relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534356/java-awt-eventqueue-invokelater-explained

Comment: read through [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), it´s simply an [anonymous object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587392/can-we-create-an-instance-of-an-interface-in-java).

Comment: Your second idea is right. As you see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) `Runnable` is an interface which needs an implementation of the `public void run`method. You can see it at the `@Override`-Tag. The `invokeLater`-method needs a Object which is `Runnable` and it is possible to define this new Object within this parameter-part. So the `run`-Method is an implementation for the new `Runnable`-Object for the `invokeLater`-Method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`run()` is main method of runnable interface.
In `invokeLater()` you pass new `Runnable` object which has to implement its own `run()` method. So what you do currently is creating anonymous `Runnable` class and passing it into `EventQueue` method.
This way of running GUI applications starts your APP in separate thread using provided `run()` method and is used for concurrency reasons - like to not to block GUI on others background operations