# Differences between anonymous inner classes and local classes

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anonymous vs named inner classes? - best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714602/anonymous-vs-named-inner-classes-best-practices)

When working with Java `Handlers` in general, people often use three approaches :

1. Create a class that will implements all needed interfaces
2. Create a `anonymous inner class`
3. Create a `local class`

I'm interested only about the **differences between 2) and 3)**

Comparing 2) to 3) we can consider the following code. In this example, **only one class** will be generated by the Compiler.

```java
class MyHandler implements ClickHandler, DragHandler, MovedHandler
    {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

        public void onMoved(MovedEvent movedEvent) {
            // Do stuff
        }

        public void onDrag(DragEvent event) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }

    MyHandler localHandler = new MyHandler();
    button.addClickHandler(localHandler);
    something.addDragHandler(localHandler);
    that.addMovedHandler(localHandler);
```

In the following example, **three inner classes will be generated** by the Compiler (correct me if I'm wrong).

```java
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent clickEvent)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
something.addDragHandler(new DragHandler()
    {
        public void onDrag(DragEvent event)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
that.addMovedHandler(new MovedHandler()
    {
        public void onMoved(MovedEvent movedEvent)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    });
```

My question is : Is there any other difference between these two approaches ? Is there any caveats of using one despite the other ?

Comment: A local class is named, can have multiple constructors and implement multiple interfaces.

Comment: @Quoi it's not really a duplicate, in this case, I'm talking about handler, and the specific fact that we often need multiple anonymous classes without the same method

Comment: +1 ok. I think too, not exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that the classes in example 1 are named and the classes in example 2 are anonymous. Functionally they are the same otherwise.

If you instead declared the class like

```
static class MyHandler implements ClickHandler ...
```

Then what you would have would be a [*static nested class* which differs from the *inner class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) in that the former does not have a reference or direct access to the methods of the enclosing class.

Comment: One might add for the question "Is there any caveats of using one despite the other ?": The named class is reusable, the anonymous ones are "one-shot" ... it's a difference rather than a caveat.